# Visual Studio 2019 C++ on Linux - error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a C++ Console project in VS2019 on Linux (a Debian VM).  I've set up the Connection Manager properly, and VS does copy the source files onto the Linux VM and attempts to compile using the g++ compiler there.  It throws a dozen or more of the same error:

> cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
> compilation terminated.

I'm a newb with the g++ compiler, as I've always just used Visual Studio on a local Windows machine.  I have no idea what the message means, which seems the place to start.  Command Line under C/C++ in Configuration Properties looks like this:

```
"g++" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type"
-W"parentheses" -W"no-pointer-sign" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" 
-W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -std=c++11 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing 
-g2 -gdwarf-2 "g++" -O0 -fthreadsafe-statics -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-
body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" 
-W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -frtti -fno-omit-
frame-pointer -std=c11 -fexceptions -I "/usr/include/apr-1.0/include" "1" -o "C:\Users\Jimbo1987 
\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\cms_example\obj\x64\Debug\%(filename).o"
```

There are indeed multiple .cpp and .h files, but there are no -c, -S, or -E flags.  I'm obviously missing something extremely simple and fundamental for not knowing how to manually feed a compiler without having it all automated for me with a makefile.

Can somebody point me in the right direction to understand this?

Comment: You have `"g++"` twice. Actually, it looks like you pasted two commads together, there are quire a few duplicates around (and surprisingly `-std=c11`)

Comment: Thank you Yksisarvinen!  That command was built automatically by Visual Studio.  I don't even know what the vast majority of it means, so I just trusted the IDE was doing it right.  Removal of that premise opens up a world of possibilities.  Now I know where to start -- studying manual compiling at the command line so I know what it all means.  That helps more than you know.